# How to read Excel column validation rules from one file and validate other similar file data

Tags: .net, excel

I have a requirement where we should allow users to upload different Excel files to fill in our data by selecting the type. I wanted to validate that data in that uploaded Excel based on the selected type and show invalid records to user to reject uploaded file. I am thinking of saving excel templates and reading them to know the validation rules if possible. How do i read a template or actual excel file with just column names and validation rules. I wanted to implement this without using any expensive 3rd party libraries. Please suggest.

Environment: ASP.net, Entity Framework and VB.NET

Thanks
YG

Comment: I have developed validator with customizable rules. Validation mechanism is based on extended `DataTable.Select()` syntax. Excel files are loaded through ACE.OleDB. Validation results are written in the same file in separate worksheet. But it's in ASP.NET / C#. Message me if you're interested.

Comment: I don't have any problem with c#, I would like to know more.